# Changing the anchor point in Three.js

Tags: three.js

Ive been playing with Three.js now for a few weeks and im planning to build something however all my measurements are from the top left front instead of Three.js that places from the central point.

Some context, I want to build Object3d's with cubes within them, but if i know the object 3d is 10/10/10 if i then add a cube of 1/1/1 at position 0/0/0 then the 1/1/1 would sit in the middle of the parent. Instead I want position 0/0/0 to put the 1/1/1 in the top left front corner.

I hope this makes sense.

EDIT: The answer to translate is not what im asking. that solution is positioning to the center and then translating it. I want the starting 0/0/0 to be in the top / left / front by default.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664898/three-js-how-to-translate-geometry

Comment: even closer duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812861/three-js-pivot-point

Comment: may also be useful to check this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1364

Comment: Thanks Westlangley, but that answer is translating, i dont want to translate, i want the origin position to not be in the middle.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the issue one, I will try follow up there.